# Checking for multiple conditions with JavaScript includes() method inside filter() method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter out words that include `zz` or `ZZ` but can't quite get it to work. I am trying to use `includes()` within the `filter()` method. I'm not sure if the `||` operand is the correct choice here.

```
function removeZZ (str){
  let splitStr = str.split(" ")
  let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word => !word.includes("zz") ||!word.includes("ZZ") )
  return noBuzz.join(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `word.toLowerCase().includes`

```js
const str = "wed zzAA ZZSS 34f34f"

function removeZZ(str) {
  return str
    .split(" ")
    .filter(word => !word.toLowerCase().includes("zz"))
    .join(" ");
}
console.log(removeZZ(str))
```

With your approach you need to use `&&` instead of `||`

```js
const str = "wed zzAA ZZSS 34f34f"

function removeZZ(str) {
  let splitStr = str.split(" ")
  let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word => !word.includes("zz") && !word.includes("ZZ"))
  return noBuzz.join(" ")


}
console.log(removeZZ(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply you can make each word lowercase and check if it includes 'zz'. Try the following example.

```
function removeZZ (str){
  let splitStr = str.split(" ")
  let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word => !word.toLowercase().include('zz'))
  return noBuzz.join(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit inverted by using the `||` instead of `&&` operator.

Instead you could write this:

```
let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word => !word.includes("zz") && !word.includes("ZZ") )
```

Or use an Array of blocked words instead:

```
let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word => !["zz", "ZZ"].includes(word))
```

Or, as they are the same and only the case is different, try a Regex:

```
let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word => !word.match(/zz/i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code , hope it will help you.
Your First error is you are not returning anything from filter method.
Second error is in or (||) condition. You have to use and (&&) condition for checking both conditions if word not contains 'zz' and 'ZZ'.

```js
function removeZZ (str){
  let splitStr = str.split(" ")
  let noBuzz = splitStr.filter(word =>{
   
    if(!word.includes("zz") && !word.includes("ZZ")){
      return word;
    }
   })
  return noBuzz.join(" ")
}

const ans=removeZZ("zz asoaZZzz aos as ZZAas Azz");
console.log("ans is : ",ans)
```